# bootstrap submit button showing blue color even after btn class added

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in my rails project and I'm using the input-append css class on an input filed and submit button. All works great except when I hover over the submit button the style turns to a blue color. Looks like its ignoring the class .btn that I set on it for its default gray color and defaulting to the blue color that a submit button has.

```
<div class="input-append">
       <%= text_field_tag :password, "", :class => 'span2' %>
       <%= button_tag "Submit", :class => 'btn'%>
</div>
```

here is what this code outputs to html.

```
<div class="input-append">
       <input type="text" value="" name="password" id="password" class="span2">
       <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Anyone else having this issue. Again it's only on the hover state.

Comment: show your css so we can have something to work with as this works:`.btn{background-color:#dddddd;}` for instance

Comment: My css is just the bootstrap css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look into the CSS to find the hover pseudo-selector that is affecting your button, and get rid of it or override it.

Comment: I have looked at it in firebug and its showing as #33333 which is not a blue color. That's whats odd.

Comment: @Chapsterj Firebug is probably showing the attributes for the element without the selector. Try adding a new line of CSS at the bottom of the file that says button.btn:hover {background:#333}